# How can I add page breaks to my SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a form output I am creating for a SSRS report. It looks the same as the form webpage but just has the answers inserted dynamically according to the user. The report is not a table listing but is just a list of questions and multiple choice checkboxes listed under each question in the report.

I need to insert a page break after questions 3, 6 and 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A screenshot of your current design would have helped a lot but assuming it's very simple you can just add a thin rectangle between questions 3 & 4. Right-click the rectangle and show it's properties, then set the pagebreak property to whatever you want. Copy and paste the rectangle between questions 6 & 7 and 7 & 8.

Comment: This works perfectly. I also had extra blank pages until I reduced the width of my working area.